# Only show one map location window at a time

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using this script to show small info windows next to each respective map location, using the Google maps API.

The problem is as you click Location 01, Location 02 etc the small windows remain open and can easily appear over top of each other, which isn't very user friendly.

What I need to do is have it so that only one of the small info windows can be visible at any given time. So for example, if I click 'Location 01' then all other info windows that might have been open will close.

You can see the fiddle in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/vm4cksue/

...or view my code here...

```
    (function($) {

function new_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        //zoom      : 14,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        scrollwheel : false,
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        }
    };


    // create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);


    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];


    // add markers
    // add identifying number to each marker
    var sidebar = 1;
        $markers.each(function(){
    add_marker( $(this), map, sidebar);
        sidebar++;
    });



    // center map
    center_map( map );


    // return
    return map;

}

function add_marker( $marker, map, sidebar ) {

    // dynamic Lat & Long
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng')
    );

    // Dynamic marker
    var icon = $marker.attr('data-icon');

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map:      map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, // animation
        icon: icon,
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : '<div id="iw-container">' + $marker.html() + '</div>'
        });

        /*
            * The google.maps.event.addListener() event waits for
            * the creation of the infowindow HTML structure 'domready'
            * and before the opening of the infowindow defined styles
            * are applied.
            */
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

            // Reference to the DIV which receives the contents of the infowindow using jQuery
            var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

            // Restyle parent DIVs
            var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

            // Removes background shadow DIV
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});
            // Removes white background DIV
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});
            // Moves the infowindow 115px to the right.
            iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '125px'});
            // Moves the shadow of the arrow 76px to the left margin.
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 26px !important;'});
            // Moves the arrow 76px to the left margin.
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 26px !important;'});
            // Changes the desired tail shadow color.
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow': 'rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6) 0px 1px 6px', 'z-index' : '1'});

            // Restyle child DIVs
            var iwBackground = iwOuter.next();

            // Set a new variable iwCloseBtn.
            var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();


            // hide default Google Maps sprite on close tag
            iwCloseBtn.children(':nth-child(1)').css({'display' : 'none'});

            // Apply the desired effect to the close button
            iwCloseBtn.css({
                width: '45px',
                height: '45px',
                opacity: '1', // by default the close button has an opacity of 0.7
                right: '0',
                top: '0', // button repositioning
                'background-image':'url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-32.png)', // adding background image
                'background-size': '25px',
                'background-position': 'center',
                'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
                });

            // The API automatically applies 0.7 opacity to the button after the mouseout event.
            // This function reverses this event to the desired value.
            iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
                $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
            });



        });

        // Create a click on the sidebar list and open the info window
            $('#m'+sidebar).click(function(){

            // Close info windows
            $.each(map.markers, function(index,value){

                if(infowindow)
                infowindow.close();

            });
            // Click on the marker
            google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
            });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open( map, marker );
        });

    }

}

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        //map.setZoom( 14 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        //map.fitBounds( bounds );
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 7 );
    }

}

var map = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        // create map
        map = new_map( $(this) );

    });

});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a window level var actOpenWindow for store the actual open window and close before open a new one

```
  var actInfoWindow = null;
```

then in your listener you shoul manage the proper situation

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (actInfoWindow){
          actInfoWindow.close();
         }
         if (infowindow!==actInfoWindow){
                infowindow.open( map, marker );
                actInfoWindow = infowindow;
         } else {
            actInfoWindow.close();
            actInfoWindow = null;
         }

    });
```

see  https://jsfiddle.net/j10axkhc/5/ for test